# adding customer attributes for orderitems in sylius

Tags: e-commerce, sylius

Is it  out-of-the-box possible to add custom attributes to orderitems in an order on sylius? e.g. you've three products in the cart and finished the order. The admin would now add additional information to each item in the order, e.g. a serial number per item.

I didn't find a way to do it out of the box in sylius. Is there a way to do it or extend some classes to add the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

*upd.*
After customize OrderItem, add service with tag sylius.order_processor.

Sample,

```
    sylius.order_processing.order_original_prive_fill:
    class: AppBundle\OrderProcessing\OrderOriginalPriceAggregator
    tags:
        - { name: sylius.order_processor }
```